# How to retrieve a PrivateKey from Azure Key Vault

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault, xml-signature, jca

I'm building a xml document signature API backed by Azure Key Vault (AKV).

> I have an asymmetric certificate imported into AKV, which is stored as [Key, Secret and Certificate].

I've managed to sign the document, but I think that I'm not getting the right key.

> The Java XML Digital Signature API need a key pair (private/public) to get some info.

I've modified a provider that I found [here](https://github.com/hmcts/azure-keyvault-jca-provider), and now the signature process is called from AKV instead of the java implementation.

The thing is, when I get a Key from AKV, only the public key is coming.
The private key is stored as a Secret, and I run into trouble when I try to convert the value into an instance of PrivateKey.

**How can I convert the *SecretBundle* value into an instance of *java.security.PrivateKey* ?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how I had converted the Secret into a certificate file. You might be able to convert that into Java.

```
$kvSecret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'VaultFromCode' -Name 'TestCertificate'
$kvSecretBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($kvSecret.SecretValueText)
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
$certCollection.Import($kvSecretBytes,$null,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$protectedCertificateBytes = $certCollection.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, 'test')
$pfxPath = 'C:\cert\test.pfx'
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pfxPath, $protectedCertificateBytes)
```

You can find more details in my post - [Manage Certificates in Azure Key Vault](https://rahulpnath.com/blog/manage-certificates-in-azure-key-vault/). You can also find some details on Exportable and Non-Exportable certificates in Key Vault and how those can be used to [sign a PDF file](https://rahulpnath.com/blog/signing-a-pdf-file-using-azure-key-vault/).

Hope that helps